# Socket is being closed? (Android & Python)

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I tried to use Sockets in my Android application, and I ran into a little problem.

I used python to create the server and everything works. The server receives the message from the Android client, but it seems like I can't get a response on the client.

This is my server side:

```python
import socket

HOST = '10.10.0.153'
PORT = 7800

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('socket created')

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print('binding faild')
s.listen(10)


while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    buf = conn.recv(1024)
    print(buf)
    data = "hello"
    conn.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
s.close()
```

This is the client side:

```java
public class Sender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final String TAG = "Sender";

    Socket s;
    PrintWriter pw;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

    String message = strings[0];

    try {
        s = new Socket(GlobalVars.SERVER, GlobalVars.PORT);
        pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

        pw.write(message);
        pw.flush();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String msg = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(msg);

        pw.close();
        s.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- Edit - I don't get this error anymore. Go down to see the new problem
  The error I'm getting is an IOException saying that the socket is closed, but I never close it.

error:

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
                  at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:935)
W/System.err:     at net.traveler.liel.traveler.Server.Sender.doInBackground(Sender.java:34)
                  at net.traveler.liel.traveler.Server.Sender.doInBackground(Sender.java:14)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/Sender: IOException 1
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you the following things:

Use **SocketIO** to connect from Python to Java. See [here](https://socket.io/)

You can also build a HTTP(S) Server with Flask and connect with your java server > [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Using raw sockets is never a good idea for production, I prefer Netty for Java applications and Spring for RESTful services.

Also, your code is running in the main thread and the Python server interrupts itself if a client disconnects.

**DONT use this Code in Production! This is insecure!**

You could also build this in Java:

```
public class NetworkServer {

public void run(String address, int port) throws InterruptedException {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.childHandler(new PipelineInjector())
                .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 4096)
                .option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(4096));


        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(address, port).sync();
        System.out.println("Network server succesfully bound to :" + address + ":" + port);
        try {
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't bind server to :" + address + ":" + port);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
```

}

And the client:

```
public class NetworkClient {

public void run(String address, int port) throws InterruptedException {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.childHandler(new PipelineInjector())
                .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 4096)
                .option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(4096));


        ChannelFuture f = b.connect(address, port).sync();

        try {
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    } }
```

This example shows a Netty client and a netty server. Netty is pretty useful and works pretty nice. Netty can be a little bit difficult but it works perfectly.

In order to use Netty **securely**, you need to encrypt all messages with **TLS/SSL**.
**Also, you should add a message queue to queue messages that could not be sent.**
There are many ways to do networking, maybe you are satisfied with one of these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `pw.close();` from your code.
Also try to remove this:

```
  if(!s.isClosed()) {
        try {
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException 2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I remove both than I don't get the error, but the socket is not being closed at any point, so I can't make another request...

Comment: Try to remove only pw.close(); and try to remove the other method without removing the other method to see which method causes the error.

Comment: If I remove pw.close(); I can't send another request.
Same goes for s.close(); If I remove it I can't make another request.

Comment: Ok, then remove the isClosed() method.

Comment: I removed the isClosed() method already.
I added a debug and found out that "String msg = in.readLine();" has an error because everything after this line is not being executed. I don't get any errors in the console so it's pretty weird.

Comment: Do you enter any input? in.readLine() waits for the users input. Try to set a String like "Hello" instead of String msg = in.readLine(); -> String msg = "Hello"

Comment: I'm supposed to receive input from the server (    "data = "hello"
    conn.send(data.encode('utf-8'))" should do it).

Comment: Try to print out the data with System.out.println.

Comment: And can you please edit your question with the whole python code?

Comment: I can't print it because I don't get any data back.
When I'm removing the readLine() it works (but I need it to get the server's response)

Comment: Okay, then edit your question with your full server.py file please.

Comment: Sadly, i couldn't get it to work. I think the python socket server works different than the java server. You could try an HTTP Server.

Answer (score 0):

On the Java side, you are asking to read a "line". A line must be terminated by a line-feed character ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())). Without the line feed, your Java code will just sit there, blocking inside `readLine()`, waiting for the line-feed to arrive. Change your python code to this:

`data = "hello\n"`